# Active tab with md-nav-bar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material navbar:

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="selectedItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="hid.overview" name="overview">Overview</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="hid.console" name="console">Console</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>

    <ui-view></ui-view>
</md-content>
```

My js file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rfApp.rffwhid', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/rffwhid', {
    templateUrl: 'rffwhid_view/rffwhid.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });

    $stateProvider
        .state({
            name: "hid",
            url: "/hid",
            template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"
        })
        .state({
            name: "hid.overview",
            url: "/view2",
            templateUrl: "view2/view2.html",
            controller: 'View2Ctrl'
        })
        .state({
            name: "hid.console",
            url: "/rffwhid_console",
            templateUrl: "rffwhid_console_view/rffwhid_console.html",
            controller: 'rffwhidConsoleCtrl'
        });



}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $state) {
    var initTab = "overview";
    $scope.selectedItem = initTab;
    $state.go("hid." + initTab);
});
```

And when i run it i get:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

It call `$state.go("hid." + initTab);` recursively :( But why ? How do i can set init tab

I use this example: http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wzLqGL

And use this template: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: What `View2Ctrl` does I somehow think that might be the case. Also I think you should remove `ngRoute` and just use `ui.router`

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij view2ctrl just show hello world like other views. But I can't remove route because this navigation is like nested view

Comment: Can you provide your actual code as a codepen please.